# How to get Qty Increments Value on Product View Page

Tags: magento2, product

In Magento 2.3 how to get Qty increments value on the product details page.
Since I am trying to use Increment and Decrement functionality based on this value.

So far I have used the below methods but no luck.

```
$block->getProductQtyIncrements()
$_product->getStockItem()->getData('qty_increments')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by below code, It can be used in
`/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

```
<?php 
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$stockItem = $_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
$increment = $stockItem->getQtyIncrements() ? $stockItem->getQtyIncrements() : 1;
//var_dump($increment);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get **Product Qty Increments** value anywhere by using below code -

**NOTE - you can use Object Manager or you can include the class in your custom class.**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$stockRegObj = $objectManager->create(\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface::class);
/* Need to pass product id and product website id */
$stockItem = $stockRegObj->getStockItem($_product->getId(), $_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
$productQtyInc = $stockItem->getQtyIncrements();
```